# Asynchronously upload multiple files with one HTTP POST

Tags: ajax, jquery, file-upload

Is it possible to asynchronously upload multiples files in the same HTTP Post request?
Basically, Can I append multiple files to FormData, and then submit all of it asynchronously at one time?

The blue-imp plugin I am using for file uploads is good, but it submits each file in a separate POST request. I just want one request ideally.

Thanks

Comment: Am also having the same problem.Did you get any idea about it???

Comment: I think there is a way to do it, but I just ended up forcing the user to zip their files. Then I inspect their files with jszip to perform validation before uploading.

Answer (score -1):

There is a free control available called Uploadify which will help you in doing in this functionality.

You'll either have to use HTML5 or flash for achieving this kind of functionality.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Thanks for the library recommendation. It would be nice if someone could answer my question in a little more detail, someone who has knowledge of HTML APIs